# How to elongate a css background image to the right without stretching and distorting it?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background-image

I'm developing a react web application using react-bootstrap and I'm currently making a navbar that has this background image. The white area is the transparent area. Later I will add clickable items in this banner in the far right part of it:

[image: Navbar]

This banner is at the top of the page and I want it to stretch to the right, all the way to the end of the page. However, I don't want the logo and page name (under the red marker lines) to stretch and distort.

How do I do that with css background magic? I could perhaps create a version of this background image that's simply so long that no windows will ever surpass it, but I don't think that's the best solution.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `width: 100%` to fill up all available space?

Comment: That doesn't make the background image longer.

Comment: what about a span filled with black background be at the back of it and set it's height equals to the right part of ur img, and make it width 100% so it can be stretched instead of the img ...

Answer (score 1):

checkout this code it might do what exactly u need
open this snipped full screen to c the effect

```css
.fgdiv {
position:fixed;
left:0;
background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNsuh.png");
background-size: auto 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index:1;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
color:red;
}

.bgspan {
position:fixed;
float:right;
width:100%;
height:19px;
top:16px;
background: black;
z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="fgdiv">text to be shown<br><br>
</div>
<span class="bgspan"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll try it out tomorrow. It looks like it's what I want, from the code snippet. But why did you use an img instead of background-image in the css? Just curious.

Comment: edited the snippet to be shown as a bg img, u can try it now ;)